# Draw communication between nodes in deployment diagram

Tags: deployment, uml, deployment-diagram

I'm drawing a deployment diagram and I have one node that communicates with a second one through TCP/IP, however, this second node also hears UDP messages from the first one, how can I model that one my diagram? Should I draw 2 lines each one with a different stereotype?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment diagrams are for depicting the structure of artifacts to be deplyed. How does the networking stuff relate to that? If you want to depict the communication within the system you are deplyoing, then try some of the interaction diagrams.